# In Django, invalid block tag url. Where am I getting this?

Tags: python, django, url

My main urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^semi_restful/', include('apps.semi_restful.urls', namespace='restful')),
```

My app's urls.py,

```
 urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
   url(r'new^$', views.new, name="new"),
   ]
```

My app's html,

```
 <a href="{% url'restful:new'%}">Add New User</a>
```

has the above link tag.

I keep getting

> Invalid block tag on line 41: 'url'restful:new'

I thought I did everything right by assigning namespace and name in urls.py.

Does anybody know what could be wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a space between the `url` and the `'restful:new'`.

Comment: Oh god, it was a space! Thank you so much. I was spending hours on this

Comment: I've added it as an answer so you can accept it and close the question. Glad it worked out :)

Comment: I just did, sorry for late reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a space between the `url` and the `'restful:new'`.

Answer (score -1):

In your app urls.py you should add:

```
app_name = 'restful'
```

And also if you named your app 'semi_restful' your links also should be

{%  url 'semi_restful:new' %}

If you do that yout app_name also should be 'semi_restful'